# Modal popups won’t run at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have a modal popup when a link is clicked in my header and one in my footer. When I comment out one of the modal scripts the other works but when both are active neither work. This leads me to believe it has to do with my JS code. I’m very new to JavaScript so the answer is probably obvious to you seasoned vets. Thanks anyway!

Also, if the html and CSS helps I can add that too.

```js
// Start Header Modal
let openModalButton = document.getElementById('modal-link');
let modal = document.getElementById('modal-content-container');
let closeModalButton = document.getElementById('modal-close-button');

openModalButton.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

closeModalButton.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
// End Header Modal

// Start Footer Modal
let openModalButton = document.getElementById('modal-disc-link');
let modal = document.getElementById('modal-disc-content-container');
let closeModalButton = document.getElementById('modal-disc-close-button');

openModalButton.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

closeModalButton.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
// End Footer Modal
```

Comment: There's an error message right here: "SyntaxError: redeclaration of let openModalButton"

Comment: Gosh I'm dumb. I was calling the same variables for both modals. Thanks though!